# Fur clumps close to skin

Tags: cats, grooming

My cat has two small clumps of fur on her neck that are very close to her skin. She's short haired, and I brush her regularly, plus she grooms herself multiple times a day. The clumps are so close to her skin that it's hard to tell that they're there unless you're petting her and you find them. Because of that, I'm not sure if it's just matted fur.

**Update:**
The mats are actually a sore. I found that out when a scab fell off of it. She's also become light-sensitive in the past couple of hours, her eyes being a little red. I should also add that last week on Thursday, she swallowed a 4-inch piece of yarn that she has not yet passed.

Comment: The sores and other symptoms you have described are _probably_ not related to the yarn. Sounds like past time for a vet visit.

Answer (score 2):

The light sensitivity and sores seem unrelated. She may have glaucoma and a skin condition.
Glaucoma is a serious, irreversible illness. She needs to be taken to a vet as soon as possible, especially if it seems like she's losing her sight.